# __USE_FILE_OFFSET64 vs. _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64

Tags: 64-bit, coding-style, standards-compliance

I am trying to maintain code that compiles on lots of different systems. I've seen a dozen different ways of asking for `lseek` that takes 64-bits. Some systems use `lseek64`, some use `lseeko`, some require that you define `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`, and now I just found a new one that requires that you define `__USE_FILE_OFFSET64`.

Is there any standard to all of this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are [getconf values in IEEE Std 1003.1-2004](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/c99.html#tag_04_12_13_03) (and a newer set in [IEEE Std 1003.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html#tag_20_11_13_03); see also the EXAMPLES section in those documents).  Actual compiler options (which might not even be defines) are not specified.

However, the `AC_SYS_LARGEFILE` macro in autoconf does not try to use this — it tries just `-n32` for IRIX, `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` (which should work for most systems) and `-D_LARGE_FILES=1` (apparently for AIX).  There is also a reference to [Adding Support for Arbitrary File Sizes to the Single UNIX Specification](http://www.unix-systems.org/version2/whatsnew/lfs20mar.html) (an older spec draft which was then partially included in the POSIX.1 spec) in autoconf sources.

As for defining `__USE_FILE_OFFSET64` manually, not sure if this is really a correct solution — double-underscore macros are reserved for system headers, and most likely there is some conditional definition there which depends on other defines.

Answer (score 13):

In `features.h`, you see the relation between `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` and `__USE_FILE_OFFSET64`.

```
#if defined _FILE_OFFSET_BITS && _FILE_OFFSET_BITS == 64
# define __USE_FILE_OFFSET64    1
#endif
```

So, only `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` is meant for the users.

Comment: Incidentally, the `defined` test is pointless in the above libc code. If `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS == 64` succeeds, then the macro must be defined; how else did it expand to 64? If the macro is not defined, then `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` will expand to `0`, and the test will fail.

Comment: @Kaz The `defined` test is to avoid warnings from gcc's `-Wundef` mode, which is used _when building libc itself_, because glibc has a _lot_ of internal configuration macros and they want to avoid typos. Because it's the build of libc itself, the headers don't get the usual exemption from warnings that gcc applies to "system headers".